# Why would firefox and google chrome not display rounded borders and Internet explorer works fine using border image?

Tags: css

Now I've tried everything I could think of to get Firefox and Google Chrome to display rounded borders, even using the moz and webkits, but it does not seem to work. Any helpful tip on what the issue might be of why Internet Explorer is displaying the way I want it to, and the other two aren't would be greatly appreciated. PIE does work well I should say.

```
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
    /* Moz  Firefox */
    -moz-transform: translate(100px, 50px);
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
     border-radius: 15px;
     border-width: 12px;
   /* WebKit - Chrome and Safari */
   -webkit-border-radius:15px;
   -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 50px);
   /* Internet Explorer 9 */
   -ms-transform: translate(100px, 50px);
   behavior: url('/PIE/PIE.htc');
   /* Opera */
   -o-transform: translate(100px, 50px);
   /* general syntax */
   transform: translate(100px, 50px);
   /* Border Changes */
    width: 1000px;
    border-style: Solid;
    border-image: url('/images/fire.jpg') 10 10 10 10 round round;  
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I have to say I haven't tried using a Fiddle before.

Comment: It might be browser use/implementation of css 2 vs css 3 and 3+ and the way that border/margins use additive vs. subtractive calculations for these values against the tag's properties themselves.

Comment: I would think that Google Chrome and Firefox wouldn't have a problem using the border-radius in moz and webkit to create the rounded borders, but after i installed the PIE.htc to Internet Explorer it shows exactly the way I want it to, but Google Chrome and Firefox do not as shown from the code above. I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: fiddle means jsfiddle.net, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5JFx8/ now just add your html code in and save/update the fiddle.

Comment: Michael Durrant so you think that the Google Chrome and Firefox is having an issue with border-image using border radius for rounded borders? If that is it, why would Internet Explorer work with PIE and then Google Chrome and firefox not?

Comment: Not sure, just throwing in ideas to see if any help.

Comment: I very much appreciate the help. I messed around with the fiddle for a bit and it didn't seem to help any. It just throws my mind for a loop that Internet Explorer is not giving an issue with the border-image and the rounded borders, but Firefox and Google Chrome will not show them.

Comment: ok I figured it out lol. The image itself inside the container was not giving off rounded corners but the border itself was rounded. Sorry for the waste of time. Thank you for the help.